# Filter associative array with keys array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following arrays:

`$keys`

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'buz' (length=3)
```

`$data`

```
array (size=3)
  'foo' => int 1
  'bar' => int 2
  'buz' => int 3
```

How to get `$data` array filtered by `$keys` values ? Desired output:

```
array (size=3)
  'foo' => int 1
  'buz' => int 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) should be able to help you out here

```
array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($keys));
```

The [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip) is needed because `array_intersect_key` operates on keys, so this makes sure both arrays are in the right format.

DEMO: http://codepad.org/AGpDAZtE

Comment: Deleted my answer, which was exactly the same, as you had answered this first.

Comment: Whoa. Rocket's quite fast. Beat me. +1 :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: I'm a ninja ^~^